# Make a hyper link on Html link with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Html contents like

```
<span> 
 http://j.mp/eUcRNK
</span>
```

I want to hyperlink on above html text like this

```
<span>
    <a href="http://j.mp/eUcRNK" class="link" target="_blank">
    http://j.mp/eUcRNK
    </a>
</span>
```

How I can do that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('span').html(function(i,txt){
   return $('<a>').text(txt).attr({'target':'_blank', 'href': txt }).addClass('link');
});
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/nH7jE/)

based on the comments below, I guess this solves it.

```
$('span').html(function(i,txt){
   return replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(txt);
});

function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
  var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
  return text.replace(exp,"<a class='link' href='$1' target='_blank' >$1</a>"); 
}
```

## [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/nH7jE/1/)

for jquery 1.3.2, just change the jQuery codes a bit.

```
var span = $('span');
span.html(replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(span.html()));
```

## [another updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/nH7jE/2/)

Comment: I want regulare expression that convert all html links to <a> link in my span tags that is not fixed that only one link are there...

Comment: ok its done. but When I tried above code on Jquery 1.3.2 version not working. but it working on latest jquery...

Comment: thanks a lot for help me..                                          I tried my slef with example                                        $("span").each(function(){
             var exp=/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
            $(this).html($(this).html().replace(exp, "<a target='_self' class='msg_links' href=$1>$1</a>"));
        }); It working..

Comment: @Reigel I have problem in above JS fiddle to make a link.. If I enter link like www.google.com then it did worked.. please help me..

Comment: what seems to be the problem?

Comment: @Rigel Thanks, If user entered "http://google.com" or www.google.com in both cases it should make a link. but in your fiddle it did not create a link.. please help me..

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("span").each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).contents().wrap("<a class='link' href='" + text + "' target='_blank' />")
});
```

Comment: but I have not only text in html contents It may varies like          "Test this link http://j.mp/eUcRNK or abcd" contents