# jTwitter -  Links aren't clickable

Tags: jquery, html, twitter, jtwitter

I have used [jTwitter](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/jquery-twitter-api-plugin.html#comment-form) (jQuery plugin for Twitter) to retrieve and display tweets on my webpage. Everything is working except the links that are in tweets aren't clickable. I have tried different ways but I couldn't find a solution.

Here's the source

**newstick.js**

```
$(document).ready(

   function(){
        $.jTwitter('user', 10, function(data){
            $('#newsticker').empty();
            $.each(data, function(i, post){
                $('#newsticker').append(
                        ' <li>'
                        // See output-demo.js file for details
                        +    post.text
                        +' </li>'
                );
            });

        $("#newsticker").newsTicker();
            parseSamples();
        });

}   
);
```

I'm also using [news ticker](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/newsticker/) plugin so that I can display tweets as a ticker

```
<ul id="newsticker">

</ul>
```

Tweets are displaying somewhat like this but the links aren't clickable

```
jQuery Beginner: Checking how many elements were selected by $('.selector') http://t.co/berI7bu

jYouTube - jQuery YouTube plugin. Gets any video’s image http://t.co/vTxSmD5
```

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) please

Comment: In the example the links also aren't clickable so you would need to test post.text for http://... and then add an anchor tag around it, also are you using the newest version of jTwitter, since the link you posted goes to version 1.0

Comment: Yes I'm using the latest jTwitter version, and yes in the example also the links aren't clickable. I will try to go with that anchor adding method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that uses regex

```
function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
        return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>"); 
}
```

This simple funcion will turn non-clickable links to clickable. Found this in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655000/make-a-hyper-link-on-html-link-with-jquery)